# Python tkinter label not appearing when using textvariable

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a high school student trying to create a quiz program that selects random true or false questions.

What I want to do is get the label `AnswerQuestionPageText2` (with the text variable `AnswerQuestionPageText2Variable`) reload when the button `AnswerQuestionPageButton4` is pressed. Before it is pressed, it should read Please click 'reload question'. However, `AnswerQuestionPageText2` doesn't show at all.

Thanks for any help. But please, **don't send hate to me**. I have already tried asking on stack overflow and that was all I got.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.font import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import random
#variables
IQ = 0
int(IQ)
#lists
TrueQuestions = [
    'true question 1',
    'true question 2',
    'true question 3',]
current_question = random.choice(TrueQuestions)
#command defines
def MainMenuButton1Command():
    MainMenu.withdraw()
    AnswerQuestionPage.deiconify()
def MainMenuButton2Command():
    pass
def MainMenuButton3Command():
    pass
def MainMenuButton4Command():
    pass
def MainMenuButton5Command():
    quit()
def AnswerQuestionPageButton1Command():
    AnswerQuestionPage.withdraw()
    MainMenu.deiconify()
def AnswerQuestionPageButton2Command():
    pass
def AnswerQuestionPageButton3Command():
    pass
def AnswerQuestionPageButton4Command():
    current_question = random.choice(TrueQuestions)
    AnswerQuestionPageText2variable.set("Question: "+str(current_question))
    AnswerQuestionPageText2variable.get()
#MainMenu
MainMenu = Tk()
MainMenu.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
MainMenu.title("IQ extreme Main Menu")
MainMenu.configure(bg="blue")
BigFont = Font(family="Tahoma",size=48,weight="bold")
SmallFont = Font(family="Tahoma",size=24)
TinyFont = Font(family="Tahoma",size=18)
MainMenuText1 = Label(MainMenu,bg="blue",fg="black",font=TinyFont,text="MAIN MENU")
MainMenuText1.place(x=1130,y=0)
MainMenuText2 = Label(MainMenu,bg="blue",fg="black",font=SmallFont,text="IQ")
MainMenuText2.place(x=400,y=75)
MainMenuText3 = Label(MainMenu,bg="blue",fg="black",font=BigFont,text="EXTREME")
MainMenuText3.place(x=500,y=120)
MainMenuText4 = Label(MainMenu,bg="blue",fg="black",font=TinyFont,text="Current IQ: "+str(IQ))
MainMenuText4.place(x=575,y=275)
MainMenuButton1 = Button(MainMenu,bg="white",fg="black",font=TinyFont,text="Start",width=20,command=MainMenuButton1Command)
MainMenuButton1.place(x=525,y=400)
MainMenuButton2 = Button(MainMenu,bg="white",fg="black",font=TinyFont,text="Upgrade",width=20,command=MainMenuButton2Command)
MainMenuButton2.place(x=525,y=475)
MainMenuButton3 = Button(MainMenu,bg="white",fg="black",font=TinyFont,text="See Data",width=20,command=MainMenuButton3Command)
MainMenuButton3.place(x=525,y=550)
MainMenuButton4 = Button(MainMenu,bg="white",fg="black",font=TinyFont,text="How to play",width=20,command=MainMenuButton4Command)
MainMenuButton4.place(x=25,y=950)
MainMenuButton5 = Button(MainMenu,bg="red",fg="black",font=TinyFont,text="Quit",width=5,command=MainMenuButton5Command)
MainMenuButton5.place(x=0,y=0)
#AnswerQuestionPage
AnswerQuestionPage = Tk()
AnswerQuestionPage.withdraw()
BigFont = Font(AnswerQuestionPage,family="Tahoma",size=48,weight="bold")
SmallFont = Font(AnswerQuestionPage,family="Tahoma",size=24)
TinyFont = Font(AnswerQuestionPage,family="Tahoma",size=18)
AnswerQuestionPage.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
AnswerQuestionPage.title("IQ extreme")
AnswerQuestionPage.configure(bg="blue")
AnswerQuestionPageText1 = Label(AnswerQuestionPage,bg="blue",fg="black",font=SmallFont,text="Current IQ: "+str(IQ))
AnswerQuestionPageText1.place(x=0,y=0)
AnswerQuestionPageText2variable = StringVar()
AnswerQuestionPageText2variable.set("Please click 'reload question'")
AnswerQuestionPageText2 = Label(AnswerQuestionPage,bg="blue",fg="black",font=BigFont,textvariable=AnswerQuestionPageText2variable)
AnswerQuestionPageText2.place(x=350,y=75)
AnswerQuestionPageButton1 = Button(AnswerQuestionPage,bg="white",fg="black",font=TinyFont,text="Home",width=5,command=AnswerQuestionPageButton1Command)
AnswerQuestionPageButton1.place(x=1205,y=5)
AnswerQuestionPageButton2 = Button(AnswerQuestionPage,bg="green",fg="black",font=BigFont,text="True",width=10,command=AnswerQuestionPageButton2Command)
AnswerQuestionPageButton2.place(x=120,y=500)
AnswerQuestionPageButton3 = Button(AnswerQuestionPage,bg="red",fg="black",font=BigFont,text="False",width=10,command=AnswerQuestionPageButton3Command)
AnswerQuestionPageButton3.place(x=760,y=500)
AnswerQuestionPageButton4 = Button(AnswerQuestionPage,bg="white",fg="black",font=TinyFont,text="Reload question",width=20,command=AnswerQuestionPageButton4Command)
AnswerQuestionPageButton4.place(x=500,y=0)
```

Comment: You've posted a lot of code that is unrelated to the question. Please try to reduce the code to a [mcve].

Comment: It is because you have used two instances of `Tk()`.  Change `AnswerQuestionPage = Tk()` to `AnswerQuestionPage = Toplevel()`.

Comment: @acw1668 Thank you. I replaced `AnswerQuestionPage = Tk()` to `AnswerQuestionPage = Toplevel()`. However, in `MainMenuButton1Command`, it reports that `AnswerQuestionPage` is not defined.

Comment: I don't have such error.

Comment: @acw1668 I am using python 3.7.2, could that be the problem?

Comment: @acw1668 The exact error message: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "IQ extreme.py", line 61, in <module>
    AnswerQuestionPage = TopLevel()
NameError: name 'TopLevel' is not defined
>>> Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "IQ extreme.py", line 18, in MainMenuButton1Command
    AnswerQuestionPage.deiconify()
NameError: name 'AnswerQuestionPage' is not defined`

Comment: You used `TopLevel()`, but it should be `Toplevel()` instead.

Comment: If you run your script in a terminal instead of using Python IDLE, you cannot execute the script due to `'TopLevel' is not defined` error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229034/discussion-between-samuel-may-and-acw1668).